# Chrome Remote Desktop not installing

Tags: chrome-remote-desktop

It was showing a discrepancy when I tried to install chrome remote desktop for my google cloud compute engine(Ubuntu) through SSH. giving the following msg:

`$sudo dpkg --install chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb`

```
Selecting previously unselected package chrome-remote-desktop.
(Reading database ... 113227 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chrome-remote-desktop (91.0.4472.10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chrome-remote-desktop:
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libgbm1 (>= 17.1.0~rc2); however:
  Version of libgbm1:amd64 on system is 13.0.6-1+b2.
dpkg: error processing package chrome-remote-desktop (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u12) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chrome-remote-desktop
```

`$ sudo apt install --assume-yes --fix-broken`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chrome-remote-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 104 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 113353 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing chrome-remote-desktop (91.0.4472.10) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you downloaded DEB package for a much newer Ubuntu than you are running. You didn't specify exactly what you are running so I have to only speculate.

The version you are using affects a lot of things, what is the output of the following?

```
lsb_release -a
```

On very old distributions you will have a lot problems installing newer out-of-distribution packages.

And I think the remote desktop needs to match the base chrome package, what happens when you run the:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

If you want to control your server remotely, did you consider alternatives?

- X11 forwarding tunnel with SSH
- NoMachine
- VNC server (I would still use it through SSH to make it more secure)
- TeamViewer